# How should I check that [out] params in COM can be used?

Tags: com, out-parameters, hresult

Officially one should not use `[out]` parameters from COM functions unless the function succeeded this means that there are (at least) three ways to see if an `[out]` parameter can be used.

Consider the following interface

```
interface IFoo : IUnknown {
    HRESULT GetOtherFoo([out] IFoo** ppFoo);
    HRESULT Bar();
};
```

Which of the following ways would you recommend on using it?

**1. Check return value**

```
CComPtr<IFoo> other;
HRESULT hr = foo->GetOtherFoo(&other);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) 
    other->Bar();
```

This makes me a bit nervous since a bug in `IFoo` could cause a `NULL` pointer dereferencing.

**2. Check the output parameter**

This depends on the fact that if a method fails it mustn't change any of the `[out]` parameters (if the parameter changed <==> it's safe to use it).

```
CComPtr<IFoo> other;
foo->GetOtherFoo(&other);
if (other) 
    other->Bar();
```

Note that this sort of happens anyway, `CComPtr`'s destructor will call `Release` if the pointer isn't `NULL` so it can't be garbage.

**3. The paranoid way, check both**

```
CComPtr<IFoo> other;
HRESULT hr = foo->GetOtherFoo(&other);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && other) 
    other->Bar();
```

This is a bit verbose in my opinion.

---

P.S. See [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705093).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to write more checks and make code a bit slower for making it more reliable option 3 is for you. Since you expect that there are bugs in the COM server it is quite reasonable to check against them.

Answer (score 2):

COM server methods that return a success HRESULT, yet set some of their output parameters to NULL are not very common. There are a few cases (IClientSecurity::QueryBlanket comes to mind) where this is used, but usually the client may expect all output parameters to be non-NULL if the method returned successfully.

It is, after all, a matter of how the method is documented. In the default case, however, I would consider 1. to be a safe way to go.